# building ember.js with rake

Tags: rake, ember.js

I'm trying to learn ember so I created a local git repository cloned from github so I could stay up to date with it.  I've never used rake before so I also downloaded and installed that from http://rake.rubyforge.org/.  Rake appeared to install correctly and when I ran rake --help I got the help options so I think it's all okay.  So then in my command prompt, I did a CD to the directory that has the github files for ember.  From my reading, since there's a Rakefile in the ember directory it sounds like I can just CD to that directly and run rake.  But when I do that I get the following errors.  I'm sorry but I have no experience with rake so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong... or if it's something in the build file?

```
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev\js\ember.js>rake
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_module.rb:25: warning: redundant nested repeat operator
c:/inetpub/wwwroot/dev/js/ember.js/Rakefile:485: warning: ambiguous first argument; put parentheses or even spaces
c:/inetpub/wwwroot/dev/js/ember.js/Rakefile:487: warning: ambiguous first argument; put parentheses or even spaces
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
c:/inetpub/wwwroot/dev/js/ember.js/Rakefile:3:in `<top (required)>' (See full trace by running task with --trace)

c:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev\js\ember.js>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install bundler (so you can get all of the gems ember's rake tasks depend on).

```
gem install bundler
```

Then, inside your ember directory:

```
bundle install
rake -T
```

Comment: Ok, I ran those commands and at first it didn't work.  So then in my ember directory I ran the gem install bundler command followed by the rest and I got further.  I now have a lib folder in the ember folder with the js file, however according to the docs, it should have also created an ember min file but I don't have one.  Here's the output after running the rake command.

Comment: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev\js\ember\ember.js>rake -T
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25: warning: redundant nested repeat operator←[31mhttps://github.com/livingsocial/rake-pipeline.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`←[0m

Comment: run ``bundle install`` inside of your ember directory. then run ``bundle exec rake -T`` to confirm everything installed correctly. That will also give you a list of available rake commands.

Comment: That's what I'm saying.  I did that and it gave me the error above.

Comment: mind posting the full output somewhere, commands, and directories you are running them in? also it would help to know your ruby version, gem version, and anything else.

Comment: I'd love to but stackoverflow's character limit doesn't let me get it all in this comment.  I'm using the latest version of ruby.  Gem is 1.8.24.  You can download a textfile here with the command prompt info. - http://uploading.com/files/get/427m78bm/ember%2Bbuild.txt